# Method overload not specific enough

Tags: typescript

I have this code :

```js
declare class Demo<T extends { [key: string]: any }> {
    find<K extends keyof T>(key: K): Array<T[K]>;
    find(key: string): any
}

const demo1 = new Demo<{ foo: number }>();
const result1 = demo1.find('foo'); // correct (number[])
const result2 = demo1.find('fooo'); // correct (any)

const demo2 = new Demo();
const result3 = demo2.find('test'); // incorrect (any[]), should be any
```

**[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwCIgLYHsA8AKvCAB4AuIAdsGgN7wDaA1iAJ4Bc8yZMAlpQHMAupyiVW8AL4A%20eLQBQ8JfABm-YHgDSxclRrwWrHCvgFpACkOdNASk4BBGDCitCDTUOkBuRcrXVLNk5uPkE7eDFWeUl5eTAcSm54UFwARngAXnhKEAB3DGx8ehUcHE5KAFcsACMQGCkLGx94xLJ4OGQKiDJ0rJScVIA6f2BzAHISnDGm%20AB6WcQcJ3A280qauoYhGziEpI6usgAmTOTCoZHxyamZ%20cXlsFXInd3Ws9wTrJz8zFxzJte%20xAnW6AGZTv0jsN1OMKNxpl45gt%20PEHk9xFsbAAaLgACxwXWA8FqEXEQA)**

The comments might speak for themselves, but basically I would like the second overload to be considered for any `find` call when no generic was passed to `Demo`. Sadly, `"test"` satisfies the constraint `keyof { [key: string]: any }`, thus the first overload is called. How could I solve this problem ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not a problem to make the class slightly more general, you can constrain `T` to `object` instead of `{[key: string]: any}` to avoid the index-signature issues. An extra `& string` in the first `find` constraint will prevent it matching non-string keys:

```
declare class Demo<T extends object> {
    find<K extends keyof T & string>(key: K): Array<T[K]>;
    find(key: string): any
}

const demo1 = new Demo<{ foo: number }>();
const result1 = demo1.find('foo'); // correct (number[])
const result2 = demo1.find('fooo'); // correct (any)

const demo2 = new Demo();
const result3 = demo2.find('test'); // correct (any)
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwCIgLYHsA8AKvCAB4AuIAdsGjgEYBW4ZAfPAN4BQ8P8AZgEtqeANLFyVGvADWIAJ44+8IgDJ4yMjCEBzFgApZcgFzwRAShMBBGDChzCAbREBdFgG5uvQdQPyTGrUptC3goSjlOAF9OTjAcSg14UFwARngAXnhKEAB3DGx8dn4cHBNKAFcsOhAYeEj9Mw84hLJ4OGRyiDI0zOScFIA6b2A9AHI+EtHG+AB6GcQcG2Z4PQqqmodnM1j4xPbOsgAmDKSCweGxicnpuYWlsFa9MLltnZbT3GPM7LzMXD1Gm89iAOl0AMwnPqHIZCEajCgaKZuWbzOL3R7PbZAA)